# Was any other sovereign wealth fund hit by sanctions in the past?

Tags: russian-federation, sanctions

> On February 28, the Biden administration slapped sanctions on the
> RDIF, a $10 billion sovereign wealth fund, and its CEO, Kirill
> Dmitriev. The fund was launched in 2011, a time of relative thaw in
> relations between Russia and the U.S. It was seen, optimistically in
> hindsight, as a way to promote market capitalism in Russia while
> Dmitriev, a budding financial star, could work with top fund managers
> around the world forging mutually beneficial relationships. The
> sanctions are not only emblematic of the speed with which Western
> countries moved to punish Putin for his war, but also the dashed hopes
> for a more friendly economic future that Moscow would share with the
> democracies of the world.

https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnhyatt/2022/03/08/sanctions-on-russian-fund-show-dashed-hope-of-moscows-cooperation-with-democracies/?sh=6d2e28a0a431

Sovereign wealth fund are generally managed to not be political, but there are a lot of oligarchies that have sovereign wealth funds like Saudi Arabia. I am wondering if other sovereign wealth funds were hit by sanctions in the past or Russia was the first country to ever suffer a sanction against one of its sovereign wealth fund.

Comment: FWIW, I think that the concept of a sovereign wealth fund is relatively new. Assets of Iran were frozen/seized following the 1979 Iranian revolution in connection with sanctions, but Iran didn't have a sovereign wealth fund in the sense we understand it today, at the time.

Answer (score 7):

If you need a single precedent:

[Treasury Sanctions Iran’s Central Bank and National Development Fund](https://home.treasury.gov/news/featured-stories/treasury-sanctions-irans-central-bank-and-national-development-fund)

The article cites Treasury Secretary Steven T. Mnuchin:

> “Iran’s Central Bank and the National Development Fund were ostensibly intended to safeguard the welfare of the Iranian people, but have been used instead by this corrupt regime to move Iran’s foreign currency reserves **for terrorist proxies**.”

---

> Sovereign wealth fund are generally managed to not be political […]

The article above says the Iranian NDF was used for financing terrorist proxies, which sounds like a strategic/political activity to me.

The [article linked in the OP](https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnhyatt/2022/03/08/sanctions-on-russian-fund-show-dashed-hope-of-moscows-cooperation-with-democracies/) also has to say this:

> “The RDIF still does have a **geopolitical value** for the Putin government,” said David Szakonyi, a George Washington University professor who has written about the fund. “It’s a **strategic tool** to develop relationships with a whole host of governments that maybe the West isn’t paying as much attention to.”

Answer (score 7):

#### Libyan Investment Authority

In 2011, during the Civil War in Libya, the UN security council issued resolution [1970 (2011)](https://documents-dds-ny.un.org/doc/UNDOC/GEN/N11/245/58/PDF/N1124558.pdf?OpenElement). Part of that was the freeze of assets owned or controled by key members of the regime and the Gaddafi family. A commitee was established to identify further assets that should be frozen. The very first one the committy named was the [Libyan Investment Authority](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/sanctions/1970/materials/summaries/entity/libyan-investment-authority):

> LYe.001
> LIBYAN INVESTMENT AUTHORITY
> Date on which the narrative summary became available on the Committee's website:
> 29 October 2014
> Reason for listing:
> The Libyan Investment Authority was listed on 17 March 2011 pursuant to paragraph 17 of resolution 1973, as modified on 16 September pursuant to paragraph 15 of resolution 2009 as “Under control of Muammar Qadhafi and his family, and potential source of funding for his regime “.